# How to return values from promises of javascript in protractor end to end testing on using element.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, protractor

How to return values from promises of javaScript in protractor end to end testing on using element.all

I have the below scenario where I want a return value.

//GenericUtil.js:

```
var blnFlag;
GenericUtilities = function(){
    this.objClick = function(objLocator){
        element.all(objLocator).then(function(items) {
            if (items.length == 1) {
                element(objLocator).click();
                blnFlag='True';
                console.log("Inside if" + blnFlag);
            }
            else {
                blnFlag='False';
                console.log("inside else" + blnFlag);
            };
        });
        return blnFlag;
    };
};
module.exports = new GenericUtilities();
```

//home_page.js:

```
var blnFlag;
var gu = require("../GenericUtilities/GenericUtil.js");
var home_page = function(){
    this.clickContinue = function(){`enter code here`
        blnFlag = gu.objClick(home_page_obj.btnContinue);
        console.log("After return" + blnFlag );
    };
};
module.exports = new home_page();
```

//The value is being returned as undefined.

Any help in fixing this issue makes my job easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both `gu.objClick()` and callback for `.then()` should return a value. In JS if you don't return a value from a function explicitly, it returns `undefined`. Also, promises are functioning asynchronously, so you should return `blnFlag` not outside the callback, but inside of it

```
var blnFlag;
GenericUtilities = function(){
    this.objClick = function(objLocator){

        return element.all(objLocator).then(function(items) {
        // ^^^ - return the result of you promise chain
        // you return a value of 'blnFlag' last, so the entire
        // promise chain will resolve to this value

            if (items.length == 1) {
                element(objLocator).click();
                blnFlag='True';
                console.log("Inside if" + blnFlag);
            }
            else {
                blnFlag='False';
                console.log("inside else" + blnFlag);
            };

            return blnFlag; // resolve promise with it
        });
    };
};
module.exports = new GenericUtilities();
```

**Update:**

To use returned value it also has to be enclosed in promises because of asynchronous behavior:

```
var blnFlag;
var gu = require("../GenericUtilities/GenericUtil.js");
var home_page = function(){
    this.clickContinue = function(){

        gu.objClick(home_page_obj.btnContinue).then(function (blnFlag) {
            // ------------------------------------------------^^^
            // here you can get the value of "blnFlag" for the "gu.objClick()" call
            // but you can use it only inside this function
            // or you can pass it to the next promise handler
            // because of the async behavior

            console.log("After return" + blnFlag );
        });

    };
};
module.exports = new home_page();
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you for answer but now I am getting Promise::275 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} as output and can you help me in resolving it to the blnFlag value.

Comment: Do you want to use this `blnFlag` value in the test code or to test it's result? (like `expect(blgFlag).toBe('True');` )

Comment: I dont want to use any assertions but I only want to use the value of blnFlag.

Comment: I've updated my answer. But you'll be able to use this value only inside a callback.

Comment: Or you can pass it to the next promise handler (`then()`) by returning it from the current promise handler.

Comment: Thanks Michael is there any approach to break the promise handler apart from returning them from one method to another ?

Comment: I do not think so. Maybe there are another ways to get your test work without involving this logic, it depends on what you are trying to achieve.